# Is it recommended to subscribe to the store (ngRx) inside a pipe?

Tags: angular, performance, ngrx, rxjs6

In some cases we need to fetch data from the store to do some work, is it ok to call the store inside a pipe ?

I want to know if this will harm my angular app and cause some **performance issues**.

***Basic example:***

```
@Pipe({name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    _result = null;

    constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {}

      transform(value: any, params?: any): any {
        this._store.select(selector).subscribe(data => {
          // traitement
        });

        return _result;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it, please post your code

Comment: there is no code, but I just want to know if a subscription and traitement of the data inside a pipe is a good idea or not, because I am afraid of causing some performance issues with this. hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 6):

You will end up with a pipe function that is basically identical to the `async` pipe, because you have to manage a subscription and mark the view as dirty when the store changes. It's a lot of work, and take a look at the async source code to get an idea of how complex it is.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts

The alternative is to use the selector with async in the template, and then pass extra parameters to your pipe.

```html
<app-component [value]="selector$ | async | myPipe:value"></app-component>
```

If you **really** must do it as your own pipe, then try extending the async pipe.

```js
@Pipe({name: 'myPipe', pure: false})
export class MyPipe extends AsyncPipe {

    _result = null;

    constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>, _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
       super(_ref);
    }

    transform(value: any, params?: any): any {
      const data = super.transform(this._store.select(selector));
      if(data) {
         // do work here
      }
      return _result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This idea looks very good, but as we know all an angular pipe fires a lot of times just in miliseconds.
is it a good idea to do such a work on a pipe ?